# Resolving javascript conflict on Wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have a javascript conflict on a Wordpress site, and I'm not sure which library is causing it or how to fix it. I've been out of action on the coding front for a while, and installing the script for the Chatra.io live chat has caused javascript elements on the site (such as floating menus) to stop functioning.

The site is www.cambridgeimmerse.com

Comment: I believe that the bug is in the prime.plugins.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need ***lodash*** before your `prime-plugins.js`, so, try something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```